# Flash hacking / intercepting / sending

Tags: c#, winforms, flash

I have a winforms control with a website loaded in there.

The website has a flash file loaded (a big webbrowser game) and I wish to know wether it be possible to "hack" into that flash game and send it commands.

Like, there's a button in the flash game which I want to click by using C# code.

I have tried messing around a bit with the shockwave player control but I didn't get far on that.

If it is possbile, I would like to get a small start or a point in the right direction on how to start working with this.

Comment: clicking a Flash button from C# should be possible although I would not recommend it... get the source of the Flash game and add an `ExternalInterface` exposing any methods you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should have the swf source code: the swf is compiled code. Then, you should add code to the source and, using ExternalInterface, you should expose some functions/methods to the cointainer.

Comment: So basicly it is not possible to intercept commands/functions (or whatever they are called in flash) after the code has been compiled?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible.

Comment: I never tried, but one can decompile the swf and recompile it with the needed code. I can't guarantee anything, I generally don't encourage this kind of things.

Comment: I did look at that option but since the game I want to "hack" is something like the facebook games (backyard monsters and such) a like, I doubt it will work properly.